# Simulink graph plotting

Tags: matlab, plot, simulink

I want to plot my graph right in simulink window, not in a separate window like clicking the block 'scope' and not by sending data to workspace. Is it posssible to plot a graph right in simulink?

Answer (score 0):

You need a `Dashboard Scope` block, seen here with a trivial example:

[image: simple demo]

Link to docs: [Dashboard Scope](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/dashboardscope.html)

Other dashboard blocks for visualisations within your model: [Dashboard blocks](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/dashboard.html)